# Can I restrict certain fields in firestore database to be only fetched by firebase admin?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a users collection in firestore, which stores some information about the user which I don't want to disclose to the user (e.g. session id). So my question is, is it possible to only allow firebase admin to fetch some fields of a doc and rest of the fields can be fetched if any user is authenticated? Is it possible with firebase security rules?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  The Firebase Admin SDK always bypasses security rules.  You should read the documentation about security rules to get started.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: I read that. It only allows security up to the document level. I haven't come across where I can set rules for specific fields of a document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have noted, [Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) "only allow security up to the document level".

Similarly, with the Client SDKs, when you fetch a document, you get the entire set of fields of this document.

(At the time of writing) Only the Firestore REST API allows to apply a [`DocumentMask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/DocumentMask) which "restrict a [get](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/get) or [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch) operation on a document to a subset of its fields". Note that **this is not a limitation on the read and write access right** at the level of the field (i.e. it does not implement/mimic a security rule), it is just a way to reduce the size of the payload passed to/received from the API.

---

So, having said that, one solution is to duplicate your data and have two different collections:

- One collection with documents that contain all the fields and that is only visible by admin users (protected with a specific set of security rules).
- One collection with documents that hold only the fields that can be fetched by any authenticated user (protected with another set of security rules, e.g. `allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;`).

To "link" the two versions of a document, you use the same document id in each collection.

One side effect of this approach is that you need to keep the docs in sync.  This synchronization could be done with a Cloud Function triggered if a doc in one of the collections is modified. Since two versions of a document share the same doc id, it is not very complex.

Comment: Well, or I could just use my way... I have written a cloud function to filter out the data. So instead of directly querying the firestore, I call a cloud function, filter the data and return the appropriate json response. It's a roundabout way, so I wanted to know if there's a direct way for this...

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi That's a very good solution too. Just note that it will cost you the cost of the query **plus** the cost of the execution of the Cloud Function.

Comment: I know, that's why I was looking for the direct way.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Following you on twitter.

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi Thanks for your message and for following! :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a collection of, let's say, "users". This collection consists of "User" documents where each field inside is considered to be public (using public/authenticated rules where any user can read). Then, inside each "User" document, create another collection called "private", which has more strict security rules that only admin/certain users can access.

The downside is that every time you get a user and you also want to get his private data, you have to make another fetch (which cost you), but it makes your user's data protected and organized.